# Qt qml alias issue

Tags: qt, qml

I'm developing a little application for smartphones, and I have a problem with alias use.
For convenience I have recreated the problem in this code snippet:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1

ApplicationWindow
{
    id:mainscreen
    property alias text2_alias: text2.text
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Rectangle
    {
        id:rec1
        y:0
        height: 40
        width:300
        border.color: "blue"

        Text {
            id: text1
            text: "aaaa"
            text2_alias:"cccc"  // <<<<<<<<<<<<< Error red underline !!!
        }


    }
    Rectangle
    {
        id:rec2

        width:300
        height: 40
        anchors.top: rec1.bottom
        border.color: "blue"
        Text {
            id: text2
            text: "bbbbb"

        }


    }


}
```

The error is: Cannot assign to non-existent property "text2_alias"
Where am I wrong?

Thanks you very much.

Comment: `Text` doesn't have property named `text2_alias`. Read [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#property-aliases) page to get more info about property aliases.

Comment: What did you expect to happen?

Comment: What the h are you trying to do here?

Comment: I would like to assign from "text1" , a string to the text property of the "text2" object

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't really make sense, hence the QML error. I think it might be a misunderstanding around aliases.

Aliases allow you to create 'references' (or 'pointers' if you prefer) to other properties, providing succinct access to those properties, or allowing them to be exposed to objects which otherwise might not have access dues to their *scope*.

When you declare `text2_alias`, you are making a reference to the `text` property of the `text2` control. This would allow another object to bind to or read the value of this text. For example, if you added the following to your code sample as another child of `mainscreen`:

```
Text {
    id: anotherTextBox
    text: mainscreen.text2_alias
}
```

(Notice I refer to the alias as `mainscreen.text2_alias`, giving the object name of the parent of the alias in order to use it). The text shown in this box would always been the same as that in `text2` ("bbbbb"). Is this what you are trying to achieve from `text1`? If so, then no alias is required, and you could achieve this my modifying `text1` as:

```
Text {
    id: text1
    text: text2.text
}
```

The [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html) on aliases explains this in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

`text2_alias` is a property of the `mainscreen` object. It's an alias to the property `text` of the `text1` object.

The `text2_alias` in the `text1` object isn't anything at all. `text1` doesn't have such a property (that's what the error says).

Comment: thanks Velkan,
I understood, but what is the workaround to achieve the properties text2  object, how do?